# Why could a function works fine in main() but not inside a class?

Tags: c++, function, class

I have to move a function which call from my main to a class constructor. However while the function works fine in the main, when moved to the class constructor it generates an error on compile time:

```
cannot convert 'Tile**' to 'Tile*' for argument '1' to 'bool set_tiles(Tile*)'
In function 'void moveObjects(Tile**)'
```

I don't understand how this could happen since both functions are called identiacally. This is my main() and my class constructor:

```
int main(){
    Tile *tiles[ TOTAL_TILES ];
    if( set_tiles( tiles ) == false ) return 1; // SETEAR LOS TILES
    currentState = new OverWorld();
    update_game(tiles);
}


OverWorld::OverWorld()
{
    Tile *tiles[ TOTAL_TILES ];
    if( set_tiles( tiles ) == false ) exit(1); // ERROR
}


bool set_tiles( Tile *tiles[] ){
}

void update_game(Tile *tiles[]){
    moveObjects(tiles);
}
```

Also I noticed the error mentions another function, I'm not sure how it's related to this but I'll copy it's code:

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message says the function is declared as `bool set_tiles(Tile*)`, but in the code you show you have `bool set_tiles(Tile *tiles[])`. Which one is it?

Comment: The problem is in the code you haven't shown. The error message suggests there's a declaration of the function `set_tiles(Tile*)` (without the square brackets). This is the function you are trying to call.

Comment: @Joni thanks, for pointing that out. I figured out what the problem was, on declaration the function was missing the []. It's strange the compiler didn't warn me about it, the error was because because the main was after the definition while the class was declared before it